# c++ produces erroneous computation results. Can this be corrected?

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I asked the following question on the "Ask Ubuntu" forum and was told that the question was inappropriate for that forum.  It was suggested that I ask my question here.  I apologize in advance if this is not the appropriate venue for this question.

I currently use java as my default language. Also I am currently running Kubuntu version 12.04. I was converting a c++ program to java and the results from the java program did not match those from the c++ program. I started looking around for the problem when I realized that the java program was producing correct results and the c++ program was not producing correct results. My question is can anyone explain why c++ produces erroneous results and can it be fixed?

I wrote two minimal programs to illustrate the problem. I also wrote a script file to display the two programs, compile and run them. The results are below. Clearly the significant digits are in the same neighbourhood, however when dealing with large powers of 10 such as the 30th power the difference is significant. Here are the results of my test programs and scripts:

Linux Pegasus 3.2.0-54-generic #82-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 10 20:08:42 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

#### c++ source

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double testValue;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
    testValue = 1.0e0 * 1.9891e30;

    cout << scientific << showpoint << right << setprecision(20)
      << "The test value = "
      << setw(25) << testValue
      << "  the test value should be 1.9891e30\n"
      << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

#### java source

```
class test
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    double testValue;
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------
    testValue = 1.0e0 * 1.9891e30;

        System.out.format 
        (
            "The test value = %.20e  the test value should be 1.9891e30%n", testValue
        );
    }   // end main
}
```

#### g++ test

The test value = 1.98909999999999988781e+30  the test value should be 1.9891e30

#### java test

The test value = 1.98910000000000000000e+30  the test value should be 1.9891e30

Clearly the value of testValue produced by the c++ program is wrong while the value of testValue produced by the java program is correct. Any and all insight into this problem will be greatly appreciated.  I have searched google and here using the search terms "c++ erroneous computation" without any significant finds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you feel this computation was erroneous?  Floating point math is subject to small differences in the values.  On a single machine with a single compiler, floating point values are deterministic, however, with different languages and different compilers, you are not guaranteed to have the same results.

My old professor Bruce Dawson gives a great overview:
http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/04/05/floating-point-complexities/
http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/07/16/floating-point-determinism/

The results you see above look just fine to me.  Perhaps you should round to 3 digits after the decimal point and use that to compare your resulting values.  With floating point you will be hard pressed to get it more accurate between different languages and compilers.

Also, I'd recommend "floating point inaccuracy" as a better Google search next time.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ code is printing out the actual value while the Java code is rounding the value. Keep in mind that the number `0.0001` just as `0.1` cannot be represented exactly in binary.

You can get it to print the actual value with `BigDecimal` which will be the same as your C++ output:

```
import java.math.*;
class test
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    double testValue;
    testValue = 1.0e0 * 1.9891e30;

    BigDecimal realvalue = new BigDecimal(testValue);
    System.out.format
    (
    "The test value = %.20e the test value should be 1.9891e30%n", realvalue
    );
}
}
```

**Output**

> The test value = 1.98909999999999988781e+30 the test value should be
>   1.9891e30

AFAIK, `double` in C++ and Java both will both hold the **same** value, but when printing them out, you see the difference.